# What kinds of stores sell multi-mode (adjustable-brightness) flashlights?

Tags: gear, flashlights

Which types of vendors sell multi-mode (adjustable-brightness) flashlights? Both online and offline vendors. Both sellers of new flashlights and used ones.

I know that outdoors stores sell them, but I'm looking for other options; I want to find a vendor closer to home than the nearest outdoors store.

Related:

- ["What characteristics should I look for in a good torch/flashlight?"](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/3124/what-characteristics-should-i-look-for-in-a-good-torch-flashlight)
- ["What makes a good head lamp?"](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/1062/what-makes-a-good-head-lamp?rq=1)

Comment: @theJollySin: Good point; thank you. I have added links to some related questions. You may also want to see the [choose-a-light checklist](http://www.candlepowerforums.com/vb/showthread.php?276972-Flashlight-Recommendation-Checklist-Updated!!) then post your own personalized question. As for this question—"What kinds of stores sell multi-mode (adjustable-brightness) flashlights?"—if I may ask, did you upvote or downvote it? :)

Comment: On DIY, we would refer to this as a "shop for me question", which is OT. Not sure if the same rules apply here.

Comment: @BMitch: Fair point. Still, my question is broader than a [usual "shop for me" question](http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/15762/where-can-i-find-non-ugly-ceiling-mounted-cfl-or-led-lamp-holders). Shopping-related questions are normally closed as "too localized". They are "unlikely to help any future visitors": but my question is very broad. Or "only relevant to a small geographic area": but mine covers at least the US and Canada. Plus, unlike the vast majority of shopping questions, mine is self-answered. Did you upvote me? :)

Comment: Here's the [original SO blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/). Trying to define how broad of a scope it needed to be before a shopping question was considered on topic was only going to result in a lot of debate and confused people asking questions, so we made is as black and white as possible. For DIY, we decided "what tool should I get for Y" and "what qualities should I look for when purchasing X" are on topic, but "where can I buy X" and "is there an X with qualities Z" are off topic.

Comment: As BMike said, this really is a shopping question, even though it's somewhat more generalized than the average one.  It could also be considered a list question, which is also discouraged across the SE network. Therefore, I'm going to close it now. If you disagree with this response, you can bring it up on [meta].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the Flashlight Wiki page ["Buying a Light"](http://flashlightwiki.com/Buying_a_Light).